# In what order are Block, Armor, and Resistance applied?

Tags: the-last-spell

In The Last Spell there are three guaranteed<sup>1</sup> ways to negate an amount of incoming damage. These are "Block", "Armor", and "Resistance". The in-game descriptions are:

**Block:** Negates (flat reduction) a portion of incoming damage.
**Armor:** Protective layer preventing health loss. Fully regenerated every turn.
**Resistance:** Decreases (or increases, if negative) incoming damage.

In what order do these three get applied to incoming damage?

---

<sup>1 Unless the enemy has an ability that bypasses these.</sup>